# Best way to record the following data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am creating a SQL Server database that records vehicle movements, cleans, repairs etc.

I am struggling with how to record the following data.

I need to record each time the vehicle is cleaned. I also need to extract the amount of time that vehicle is cleaned over the past 28 days and make an average

So far I have a master table with the following columns:

```
Callsign, Registration, Location, Date Last Cleaned.
```

Then, as a work around I have "vehicle specific" tables which is where I record it each time it is cleaned.

however as I am working the ASP.net, the only way I can find to access the clean dates is by doing a foreach loop through each of the vehicle tables and returning the count of dates in the past 28 days. the problems with this I cannot work out how do this in 1 data connection instead of multiple requests to the server.

Here is a snippet of the code, but you can see that it runs through each of the check box list, and if "true" then will add to the vehicle specific table

```
 string constr = myconstring;

 SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(constr);
 SqlTransaction transaction;

 for (int i = 0; i < checkboxlistAM.Items.Count; i++)
 {
     string callsignString = checkboxlistAM.Items[i].Text;

     if (checkboxlistAM.Items[i].Selected == true)
     {
         string declare = "declare @morning datetime declare @date datetime declare @counting int ";
         string setting = " set @date = DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, getdate()), 0) set @morning = dateadd(hh, 7, @date) set @counting = (select count([made ready]) from["+callsignString+"] where[Made Ready] = @morning) ";
         string insertmorning = " if @counting <>1 insert into ["+callsignString+"] ([made ready]) values (@morning) ";

         string QueryVehicleSpecificTable = declare + setting + insertmorning;
         string QueryMasterTable = "update Shropshire SET[last made Ready AM] = GETDATE() where Callsign = '"+callsignString+"'";

         cnn.Open();
         transaction = cnn.BeginTransaction();

         SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(QueryVehicleSpecificTable, cnn);
         cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

         SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(QueryMasterTable, cnn);
         transaction.Commit();

         cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
         cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

         cnn.Close();
     }
     else if (checkboxlistAM.Items[i].Selected == false)
     {
         string declare = "declare @morning datetime declare @date datetime declare @counting int ";
         string setting = " set @date = DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, getdate()), 0) set @morning = dateadd(hh, 7, @date) set @counting = (select count([made ready]) from[" + callsignString + "] where[Made Ready] = @morning) ";
         string deletemorning = " delete from ["+callsignString+"] where [Made Ready] = @morning";
         string queryDeleteRecordfromVehicleSpecific = declare + setting + deletemorning;
         string QueryMasterTable = "update Shropshire SET[last made Ready AM] = null where Callsign = '" + callsignString + "'";

         cnn.Open();
         transaction = cnn.BeginTransaction();

         SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(QueryMasterTable, cnn);
         SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(queryDeleteRecordfromVehicleSpecific, cnn);

         cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

         transaction.Commit();

         cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
         cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
         cnn.Close();
     }
}
```

As you can see this loop has approx. 42 iterations in the morning and afternoon (84 altogether) and opening and closing the connection each time is going to slow everything down.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can make this better.

Either by making a new "cleaning" table, but then how can I keep track over 28 days instead of forever.

Or by copying each of the "vehicle specific tables" to 1 DataTable and then somehow updating them again after altering them?!?

Any ideas or questions are welcomed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you make a separate cleaning table to record every instance of a clean, you can easily restrict it to the last 28 days (or any other time period) using the where clause of the query you run when you want the results for how many cleans it's had.

Comment: Any reason why you are opening & closing the connection - can't you do that outside of the loop? Also, you seem to Commit the transaction before you actually execute the commands.

Comment: @ADyson thanks, I followed your advice, have made a separate table with 2 columns 1 for date and another for times cleaned on that date. then a simple SQL query to delete any record that is over 28 days. and foreach check box in the cleaned form will enter a number in the amount cleaned. thank you for your help

Comment: @PaulF I thought I had tried in the past to keep the connection open outside the loop but I thought I kept getting an error, possibly, I didn't try it properly, anyway I have made the table mentioned above and should be recording the data I need now. thanks again for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer your question, I have to point this out:

```
where Callsign = '"+callsignString+"'"
```

This is called SQL concatenation, and it allows for SQL injection, which is the [#1 security vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Top_Ten_Cheat_Sheet) in software today. Never do this. Use [parametrized SQL queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) all the time.

Now to answer your question.

> opening and closing the connection each time is going to slow everything down.

That's probably true, but you should obtain proof that it is a performance problem before you decide to optimize it.

Like @PaulF mentions, you don't need to close the connection every time. Move the code that opens and close the connection outside of your loop.

Another technique is to create a [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure) in your database that would do all this logic in TSQL. That way you can provide only the callsign to the stored proc and it would execute all 84 operations inside a single SQL command. The disadvantage of this approach is that stored procedures are generally a little more expensive to maintain and refactor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guillaume-cr I have updated the code to remove the concatenation and replaced all with parameters.add/add with value. the opening and closing connections was slowing everything down but I understand that I needed proof first. I have decided to follow @adyson advice and create an entire new table.